# Use property leftItemsSupplementBackButton of UINavigationItem Class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

In my app I want to show a button item together the back button in the navigation bar. I read the doc of the `UINavigationItem` class and I found the property `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` that seems to be just for me. Then I used this line of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.navigationItem setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton:YES];
}
```

But when I run the app I get this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationItem setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10faefb0'
```

and the 0x10faefb0 instance is:

```
_navigationItem UINavigationItem *  0x10faefb0
```

From the error seems that `self.navigationItem` doesn't have this property as is said in [the apple class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItem). Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Which is your target iOS Version within your plist ?

Comment: I know what you mean, I've seen now in the reference class that this property is available in iOS 5.0 and later, and my ios target is 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's for iOS 5 only.  Are you running on iOS 4?